# Button functionality in Fragment representing a list

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have a `Fragment` representing a list of items.

This is done using a RecyclerViewAdapter. I have implemented an `OnListFragmentInteractionListener` and therefore if I click an item in the list my app does something.

That works correctly. However, I decided I want to also add a button inside that item. So if I click anywhere other than the button but inside that item's borders, it will proceed with functionality as before, but if I click on the button, it will do something else.

My question is, where do I implement this functionality?

The XML file representing an item in the list is just a couple of text views and a `FloatingActionButton`.

I thought I have to implement this in my adapter, but where exactly? My adapter looks like this:

```
public class ContractRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContractRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Contract> mValues;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ContractRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Contract> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_contract_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mSell.setText(mValues.get(position).getSell());
        if (holder.mDescription != null) {
            holder.mDescription.setText(mValues.get(position).getDescription());
        }

        // TODO: Get the price from parameters?
        holder.mPrice.setText(((Double) new Random().nextDouble()).toString());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public void addContract(Contract contract) {
        mValues.add(contract);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mSell;
        public final TextView mDescription;
        public final TextView mPrice;
        public final FloatingActionButton mBtn;
        public Contract mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mSell = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.company_text);
            mDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contract_description);
            mPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_text);
            mBtn = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.buy_button_from_list);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mSell.getText() + ", " +
                    mDescription.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that wherever I implement the `onClickListener` for my `FloatingActionButton` I'll need to have access to my SharedPreferences, so I think I will have to implement it in an `Activity` class (or `Fragment` class). Is that true? If I go this way then I'll have to implement it in the `Fragment` whose content is this view, but then how will I know the position of the item selected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another method inside your `interface`,

```
private interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onListFragmentInteraction(Contract mItem);

    void onButtonClicked(Contract mItem); // You may want to edit the arguments of the method

}
```

Implement the `onButtonClicked` in your activity and do your stuff there.

Call the method inside your `onClick` of the `Button` as follows,

```
holder.mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (null != mListener) {
            mListener.onButtonClicked(holder.mItem);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> how will I know the position of the item selected?

To get the position of item selected you can utilize the `getAdapterPosition()` method of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`'s class inside your `View.OnClickListener`.

```
holder.btnXyz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Model item = items.get(position);
            /** your code **/
        }
    });
```